# Can I add ASP.NET AJAX Extentions to a page programmatically (server side)?

Tags: asp.net-ajax, controls

In a page, on the load event, I am dynamically creating controls for display on the page. This is all working properly. the trouble I am having is when adding extenders from the AJAX control toolkit, specifically I am trying to add rounded corners to a button control. No errors are thrown, but the AJAX Extension functionality does not appear in the displayed page.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I am not doing correctly, or if its even possible?

```
Dim container As HtmlGenericControl
Dim edit As Button
Dim editRoundedCorners As AjaxControlToolkit.RoundedCornersExtender 

For each item in items
            container = New HtmlGenericControl("div")
            container.ID = "container_" & item.code

            edit = New Button()
            edit.ID = "edit_" & item.code
            edit.Text = "Edit"
            edit.Style("padding") = "0 0 0 4px"
            edit.SkinID = "smallEditButton"

            editRoundedCorners = New AjaxControlToolkit.RoundedCornersExtender()
            editRoundedCorners.BorderColor = edit.BorderColor
            editRoundedCorners.ID = edit.ID & "_RoundedCorners"
            editRoundedCorners.Corners = AjaxControlToolkit.BoxCorners.All
            editRoundedCorners.Radius = 3
            editRoundedCorners.TargetControlID = edit.ID

            container.Controls.Add(editRoundedCorners)
            container.Controls.Add(edit)
            pageContainer.Controls.Add(container)
Next
```

(pageContainer is a div on the page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot apply a RoundedCornersExtender to input elements such as TextBox or Buttons.

Comment: After much digging, this is the unfortunate truth.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the "editRoundedCorners" to the page, or containers, Controls collection, so try adding the line:

```
Controls.Add(editRoundedCorners)
```

just before "'add them to page control collection" as you may only be adding the edit button, whereas both are required.

Comment: I revised my example to include the means that I am using to add to the page. (There is actually an HTML table getting built with the loop, but I have not included it for simplicity.) 

Is this what you mean?

Comment: The number of times I've added the control but *not* the extender to the controls collection - it was worth checking =)

Answer (score 2):

I'm using C#, so I'll be using that syntax.

As Rob said, you'll need to add the Extender to the page.  You can do this by:

```
*parentCtrl*.Controls.Add(*extendername*);
```

or, alternatively

```
*controltype* *controlname* = (*controltype*)Page.LoadControl(typeof(*controltype*), new object[]{});
```

If you're passing parameters on to the control, put them in the object array.

Comment: Hi, 
So you are saying that the extender control should be added to the control collection of the TargetControl? 

I also have found that there are no problems with other extensions (modal, etc). Its just the rounded corners.